# Cannot find local variable, which is a public class

Tags: java, unit-testing, nullpointerexception, static-methods, cannot-find-symbol

I am getting a null pointer exception when running a unit test because of this line:

```
ClassA.getInstance().getActive();
```

The above line is written in some other public abstract class which gets called by the test.

Here `ClassA` is a public class defined in the same package of the test file and `getInstance()` is a public static method defined in `ClassA`. When I run in the debug mode I can see that I am getting

> "Cannot find local variable 'ClassA'"

Error for `ClassA`, hence `getInstance()` is `null`.

Apologies for not publishing the full code as it is against my company policies.

Comment: Can you share code?

Comment: If you can't publish the exact code, can you not just publish a mocked up version which we can run that has the same problem? (See: [mcve])

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. First, when you say "ClassA is a public method" do you mean "ClassA is a public class"? Secondly, if the compiler cannot find a variable, that's a compilation error, not a NullPointerException. Perhaps your test is not running the code you think it is running?

Comment: The classes are very huge and very old to create a mock version. what I am wondering if anyone can tell me that in what scenario I can get a 'cannot find local variable' error while trying to access a public class in the same package?

Comment: did you import it?

Comment: @DodgyCodeException my bad, ClassA is a public class. I am running the correct test and I saw the ' Cannot find local variable' error in the debug mode while evaluating expression. The error I am getting when the test run is complete is null pointer exception because getInstance is null.

Comment: @PhilippSander I dont think I need to import it since the test file and ClassA are in the same package. And even when I try to import it, intellij suggests to remove the import since it is redundant

Comment: I see. The error message comes from the debugger when a variable is not in scope at the time. You should set a breakpoint at `getInstance()` and step into it and see why it returns null.

Comment: With maven/gradle there is src/main/java and src/test/java and main must be compiled first. Clean build. And when debugging all on the class path.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException here is some code...

m_instance is a private static ClassA field.

public static ClassA getInstance() {
return m_instance;
}

what should I debug in this

Comment: How do you declare the field `m_instance`? Do you actually initialize it to `new ClassA()`?

Comment: I think you are right. m_instance is just declared and not initialized. It is initialized in another constructor. But since getInstance() is a static method I was using it directly such as ClassA.getInstance(). should I initialize the varibable m_instance in getInstance method as well? or I should call the method as new ClassA().getInstance(), which gives a warning since getInstance in static.

Comment: You should probably update your question, there is plenty of new information in your comments. It looks to me like ClassA is a singleton and there is several ways to implement one but one way to solve the null pointer problem would be to initialize `m_instance` directly, `private static ClassA m_pointer = new ClassA();`

Answer (score 0):

Please check ClassA.getInstance() returns any Object? or null value.

In your code is ClassA.getInstance().getActive(); that means -> getInstance() return some object, please check it is return object or null.

I thought that your getting null that is reason your getting nullpointer exception.

Answer (score 0):

Try to generate object with the 'static' word.

Good luck,

G.